# Dynamic SQL fails on escape char

Tags: postgresql, escaping, procedure

I am trying to write a procedure that loads a csv into a table. I create a dynamic sql and execute it.

```
v_sql = '\copy test_table from' || ' '''  || p_temp_dir || ''' '  || ' with csv header;';

 --insert into test
 --select v_sql;

EXECUTE v_sql;
```

When I check the generated string it is fine and I can run it properly, but if I run it from a procedure, I get an error:

```
syntax error at or near "\"
```

If I remove the `\` character it works (throws an error that there is no such file; this job is intended to work on the local machine). How can I execute this SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\copy` is a `psql` command, not an SQL statement.

You can only execute SQL statements with PL/pgSQL's `EXECUTE` statement.

You cannot import a file from the client machine in a PostgreSQL function that runs on the server. You will have to write client code that does `COPY ... FROM STDIN`.

Comment: and how can i execute the generated dynamic sql in this case?

Comment: Basically not at all. I have added more to the answer.